# How can I guarantee update on the latest row in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

Assume I have a table named `table_config`:

```
id ,bigint(20),primary key,
table_id, varchar,
x, varchar,
y, varchar
active, tinyint
```

Every table_id should only have 1 `active` record.  Everytime I want to update `x` , I create a new record from old for that table_id and set active=0 for the old one.

Now I want to just udpate `y` without create a new record. So I
am doing the following steps in my java application:

1. read the old record.
2. set `y` to new value.
3. update the record by primary key(id)

My problem is, when I update the record, **how can I guarantee there is no new record that change `x` during I doing above steps, or, How can I guarantee I update y on the newest record for table_id?**

Will this work?:

```
UPDATE table_config
set y='y'
where id=(SELECT id from table_config whre table_id=`table_id` and active=1);
```

Thank for concerning.

Comment: You're asking about race conditions if there are concurrent changes to the table. If you are always reading the latest "old record", then only 1 change to the database table should be happening at any time. Try using `synchronized` to sequence concurrent calls to the mysql code https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized

Comment: @LoveenDyall Is a java-based solution appropriate for a mysql-based question? Why not Fortran?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to point out articles on race condition and thought java synchronized would be the better place to start. That comment wasn't java specific nor are race-conditions :)

Comment: Thanks but I know how to do it in JAVA, I just want to know if there is a pure mysql solution to the problem